# Do PDF::Reuse populated forms work properly on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, pdf

I'm trying to generate PDF files by taking a form template and populating the field values.  I'm trying to do it using pure Perl, because I had issues using pdftk in the past.

The PDF::Reuse module appears to be able to do it, with code like the following:

```
prFile('test.pdf');
prMbox( 0, 0, 288, 384 );
prField('vendor','This is a test');
prDocForm( { file => 'receipt-header.pdf' } );
prEnd();
```

But when I open the resulting PDF, the form fields are not populated.  Looking at the file, I can find the code that is supposed to populate it, in the form of a JavaScript snippet.  It appears to run some kind of initialization code that checks for the existence of the form field, and if found, gives it a value.

My question is: does this technique work on a Mac?  Am I experiencing a problem with PDF::Reuse, or a problem with Finder / Preview not executing that JavaScript?

For reference, my original form PDF is [here](http://arrowwood.org/receipt/receipt-header.pdf) and the resulting generated PDF is [here](http://arrowwood.org/receipt/test.pdf).

Comment: The PDF links are giving 404 Not Found error

Comment: DOH!  Fixed.  Thanks!